# How to compare two array in php

Tags: php, arrays

```
while($row = $update_post->fetch_array()){
                        //Explodes checkbox values
                        $res = $row['column_name'];
                        $field = explode(",", $res);

                        $arr = array('r1','r2,'r3','r4','r5','r6');

                            if (in_array($arr, $field)) {
                                echo "<script>alert('something to do')</script>";
                            }else{
                                echo "<script>alert('something to do')</script>";
                            }
    }
```

How to check if value of $arr is equal to the value of $field.

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: u need to use `array_intersect`, in_array will not work here

Comment: check the response in chat...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to match two array than you need to use [`array_intersect()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-intersect.php) here.

If you want to check specific value with [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.in-array.php) than you need to use loop here as:

```
<?php
$res = $row['column_name'];
$field = explode(",", $res);
$arr = array('r1','r2','r3','r4','r5','r6');
foreach ($arr as $value) {
    if(in_array($value, $field))   {
        echo "success";
    }
    else{
        echo "failed";   
    }
}    
?>
```

*[**According to manual:**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) in_array — Checks if a value exists in an array*

**Also note that, you have a syntax error in your array:**

```
$arr = array('r1','r2,'r3','r4','r5','r6'); // missing quote here for r2
```

**Update:**

If you want to use `array_intersect()` than you can check like that:

```
<?php
$arr1 = array('r1','r2');
$arr2 = array('r1','r2','r3','r4','r5','r6');
$result = !empty(array_intersect($arr1, $arr2));
if($result){
    echo "true";
}
else{
    echo "false";
}
?>
```

**[DEMO](https://eval.in/674615)**

**Update 2:**

If you want to check which value are you getting by using `array_intersect()` than you can use like:

```
<?php
$arr1 = array('r2');
$arr2 = array('r1','r2','r3','r4','r5','r6');
$result = array_intersect($arr1, $arr2);
if(count($result)){
    echo "Following ID(s) found: ".implode(",",$result);
}
?>
```

**[DEMO](https://eval.in/674622)**

Comment: What if the value of $field is 'r1','r2','r3' only. is array_intersect return true?

Comment: @oo7: no array_intersect only return the matched array

Comment: is their anyway on how to know if $field is equal to any index of $arr?

Comment: let's assume that $field = r2,r3. then how can I identify than r2,r3 are location to the $arr?

Comment: @oo7: yes friend, you can use in_array

Comment: check the UPDATE 2 @oo7

Comment: it's working. But I have 6 checkbox. if $field is return r2,r3 then i want to automatically  checked the r2,r3 checkbox. And my checkbox is generated by a loop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127695/discussion-between-oo7-and-devpro).

Comment: @oo7: check the response in chat

Answer (score 1):

compare two array by array_intersect then check with `count` to know matches array value has...

> ## array_intersect
>
> Compare the values of two arrays, and return the matches:

```
while($row = $update_post->fetch_array()){
    //Explodes checkbox values
    $res = $row['column_name'];
    $field = explode(",", $res);

    $arr = array('r1','r2','r3','r4','r5','r6');

        if (count(array_intersect($arr, $field)) > 0) {
            echo "<script>alert('duplicate array')</script>";
        }else{
            echo "<script>alert('something to do')</script>";
        }
```

}

Comment: if $field return a value of r2 then compare if $arr had a value of r2. then return true. How could I do that?

Comment: it is not return true , it return match array .Let say if $field has value of r2 ,then compare with $arr had a value of r2 ,if it has it will return that matches array !!! So count that return array has more than 0 it means it has matches array

Comment: in that case can we identify the index location of the matched in $arr?